# SSO for strings stored in std::map

Tags: c++, stdmap, stdstring

**SSO** enables short strings to be stored on stack. What if I have a `std::map<std::string, std::string>` (or any std container for that matter) which consists mainly of short strings (1 to 10 characters), and it grows to a big size (let's say **200,000** pairs). With average length of 5, this will take up around 2 MB on characters alone, which is more than enough to cause stack overflow if SSO will work for all the strings.

So the question is: how likely is the stack overflow? How exactly SSO will work in that case (MinGW 6.0, C++14, Windows 10  x64 machine)?

Comment: Completely unlikely. Feel free to create a map with a million string keys. It won't use any more stack space than a completely empty map.

Comment: While SSO stores the data locally, in the string, the data itself (the string object) is already stored in the heap as that is where `std::map` allocated its node.

Comment: The string data will be stored on the stack with SSO only if the string object itself is on the stack. This is not the case for strings in containers like `vector` and `map` where the elements are on the heap.

Comment: You've already paid the price of SSO by using a `std::string`.  It's own static size is what controls how many character it can support using SSO.

Comment: *So the question is: how likely is the stack overflow?* -- `struct S { char foo[20]; };` -- `S *pS = new S;` -- Is the `foo` array in `pS` on the stack or heap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your notion of "stored on the stack" is wrong. The `std::map` allocates its elements dynamically. Whether the `std::string` will dynamically allocate the characters is then not that relevant anymore.

What you store on the stack is `sizeof(std::map<std::string,std::string>)` and that is a compile time constant. It does not change with number of elements or length of the strings.

Comment: I did not understand that SSO applied only to statically created strings. That makes it clear

Comment: @GaussGun SSO applies to all strings. An object does not know if it lives on the stack or on the heap. `sizeof(std::string)` or in general `sizeof(any_type)` is a compile time constant

Comment: then I am confused again. If SSO is applied, it doesn't necessarily mean that the string is stored on stack?

Comment: @GaussGun no. You would not, but you can `auto* x = new std::string;`. Nothing is stored on the stack here. And the string does not care. It will do SSO as usual. The size occupied the stack of a `std::map` is always the same. In general the `sizeof(T)` is a constant for any type `T`

Comment: @GaussGun suppose you would manually manage a dynamically allocated array via a raw pointer (you should not!). Then you do `string* x = new string[42];` to have an array of 42 strings. What is stored on the stack is a single pointer. Thats not what the map does, but it is similar enough to understand that adding characters to the string does not affect how much memory the array or the map occupies on the stack

Comment: Oh, OK I understand now. There isn't a "magic compiler trick" that always puts a short string on the stack, it is just stored within the string and inherits the string's type of memory

Comment: @GaussGun frankly I have the impression that you are going to fast. If you understand SSO fully, then you know that the memory a string occupies on the stack does not increase when the string grows. You do not need to place the string in a map to understand that.

Comment: @GaussGun "There isn't a "magic compiler trick" that always puts a short string on the stack, it is just stored within the string and inherits the string's type of memory" yes. `std::string` is just a custom class that you could write yourself (it would take you a couple of years, but its doable, fortunately others did it already ;)